# Flyway on production database - Migration Checksum mismatch

Tags: mysql, maven, flyway

Every time I change something from DB structure I create a new migration file using timestamp to execute in order, with a clean database the migrate command (with maven plugin or command-line tool) it works perfectly, but in a production database, with the same DB structure but with data added I got this error:

> Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:3.2.1:migrate
>   (main) on project eee-ejb: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException:
>   Validate failed. Migration Checksum mismatch for migration 1430224929
>   [ERROR] -> Applied to database : -1639634536 [ERROR] -> Resolved
>   locally    : -1412099238

How can I use flyway in a production database where data is constantly added?

Comment: Did you got it's solution ?

Answer (score 6):

The script that was originally ran is now changed. If you are sure that the change is what you'd wanted, run

> ./flyway [repair](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/repair)

This will accept the change, update the metadata table and you will not get the error.

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with data being added. It is the migration script itself that is being modified. One place to check is Git CRLF normalization issues.

**Update:** Flyway 4.0 now automatically takes care of this.

Comment: The problem was the sequence of migration, i am using timestamp for it, thanks for the reply.

Comment: getting same issue working on local but not in production DB, is any other way to fix this ?

Comment: How is this handled as of 4.0? I'm running into the checksum mismatch error on 5.1.1 and believe the only thing to be different is Git CRLF. It works from my local machine via docker container, but fails on the build server. Source history has no change on the file in question.

Comment: @Claudinei Did you figure out? I have a prod migration and added new file in next development and now its show the new file as "Ignored". How do I over come this?