# Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed. Migration Checksum mismatch for migration 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

I tried to find the solution for the below problem, but none of them worked for me. I am developing **Angular + Spring Boot** application using **MySQL + flyway**. Please guide whats going wrong here.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed. Migration Checksum mismatch for migration 2
-> Applied to database : 1499248173
-> Resolved locally    : -1729781252
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.boot.App.main(App.java:9) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed. Migration Checksum mismatch for migration 2
-> Applied to database : 1499248173
-> Resolved locally    : -1729781252
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doValidate(Flyway.java:1108) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.access$300(Flyway.java:62) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1012) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1006) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1418) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1006) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

**application.properties**

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG

server.port=8080

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

## For H2 DB
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/dasboot
#spring.datasource.username=sa
#spring.datasource.password=
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

## For MYSQL DB
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dasboot
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.datasource.max-active=10
spring.datasource.max-idle=8
spring.datasource.max-wait=10000
spring.datasource.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=1000
spring.datasource.min-idle=8
spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=1

flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=false;

#datasource.flyway.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/dasboot
#datasource.flyway.username=sa
#datasource.flyway.password=
#datasource.flyway.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver


datasource.flyway.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dasboot
datasource.flyway.username=root
datasource.flyway.password=root
datasource.flyway.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <name>das-boot</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**V2__create_shipwreck.sql**

```
-- For H2 DB
--CREATE TABLE SHIPWRECK(
--  ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
--  NAME VARCHAR(255),
--  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(2000),
--  CONDITION VARCHAR(255),
--  DEPTH INT,
--  LATITUDE DOUBLE,
--  LONGITUDE DOUBLE,
--  YEAR_DISCOVERED INT
--);

CREATE TABLE `dasboot`.`shipwreck` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `DESCRIPTION` VARCHAR(2000) NULL,
  `CONDITION` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `DEPTH` INT NULL,
  `LATITUDE` DOUBLE NULL,
  `LONGITUDE` DOUBLE NULL,
  `YEAR_DISCOVERED` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`));
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flyway on production database - Migration Checksum mismatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29920122/flyway-on-production-database-migration-checksum-mismatch)

Comment: `mvn flyway:repair` solved my problem. It seems even you have not successful migration you need to remove it. Thanks to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41147768/caused-by-org-flywaydb-core-api-flywayexception-validate-failed-migration-che#answer-50718584

Answer (score 126):

Flyway is comparing the checksum of the SQL script with that of the previously run checksum.  This exception typically occurs if you change a SQL script that has already been applied by Flyway, thus causing a checksum mismatch.

If this is development, you can drop your database and start the migrations from scratch.

If you're in production, never edit SQL scripts that have already been applied.  Only create new SQL scripts going forward.

Comment: I simply migrate database from H2 DB to MYSQL. Then I simply updated the V2__create_shipwreck.sql. Please guide how I can solve it. I edited V2__create_shipwreck.sql in the above post. Even shipwreck table not created in MYSQL.

Comment: Drop the database and rerun Flyway and it'll rebuild it from scratch.

Comment: Drop database ? If you have a lot of test data ? Drop is not the solution. It works but its not how to fix the issue.

Comment: @Djalas As my answer indicates, changes should always be added to new SQL scripts, not existing SQL scripts.

Comment: I get what you mean. But if you you have ran a bunch of integration tests prior to checksum error. Dropping the database will wipe out your database and perhaps useful test data. Applying migrations wont give you test data, Integration tests will. I have dropped my times in the past but only for when I dont care about the data I have stored in my local postgres instance.

Comment: @Djalas Late to the party, but your integration tests should preferably be fully automated and "stateless" (between runs). Built up your integration DB data with e.g. pre-seeded SQL or similar (or even populate it from Java code), then run Flyway migrations towards that DB. Testcontainers is of great help for this, https://testcontainers.com/

Answer (score 68):

Here the solution which worked for me when I had this issue in my local system.

1. Go to flyway_schema_history in your DB
2. Delete the row containing the sql migration script

Comment: In my case, the table's name is schema_version.

Comment: how can i do at H2?

Comment: deleting the row didn't work in my case, i needed to delete the whole db schema and recreate from scratch

Answer (score 38):

I had the same issue and deleted the complete schema from the database, yet the issue remained.

I solved this by running the `repair()` command of flyway:

```
flyway.repair();
```

Alternatively with Flyway Maven plugin:

```
mvn flyway:repair
```

Maven plugin addition into pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4</version>
</plugin>
```

BTW: I did not find what exactly went wrong.

With Gradle (as per comment from [Raf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1225551/raf)):

```
./gradlew flywayRepair
```

Comment: where did you write this script.?

Comment: That was after initializing Flyway, e.g. 
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    flyway.setDataSource(dataSource);
    flyway.repair();
    flyway.migrate();

Comment: If you are using gradle then `./gradlew flywayRepair` does the trick

Comment: Thanks, this answer should be on the top.

Answer (score 17):

The best solution would be to do these steps :

1. Delete the file called - V2__create_shipwreck.sql, clean and
   build the project again.
2. Run the project again, login into h2 and
   delete the table called "schema_version".

   > drop table schema_version;
3. Now make V2__create_shipwreck.sql file with ddl and rerun the project again.
4. Do remember this, add version 4.1.2 for flyway-core in pom.xml like

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
       <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
       <version>4.1.2</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

It should work now. Hope this will help.

Comment: I can't delete schema_version. what should i do?

Comment: you can delete just the row that you are having troubles with, e.g : delete from schema_version where version = 2;

Comment: Use this instead:

drop table "schema_version";

Comment: This fixed mine, however, I needed to use: drop table "flyway_schema_version";

Answer (score 11):

IF YOU ARE NOT IN PRODUCTION, you can look in your `flywayTable` in the data base and remove the line which contain the name of the script which has been applied.

`flywayTable` is a project option which define the name of the table in the db used by flyway which contain information about the version of this db, already applied scripts...

Comment: This is it my friend ! the best solution  regarding this error in dev env. thanks

Answer (score 11):

I would simply delete from schema_version the migration/s that deviates from migrations to be applied. This way you don't throw away any test data that you might have.

For example:

```
SELECT * from schema_version order by installed_on desc

V_005_five.sql
V_004_four.sql
V_003_three.sql
V_002_two.sql
V_001_one.sql
```

Migrations to be applied

```
V_005_five.sql
* V_004_addUserTable.sql *
V_003_three.sql
V_002_two.sql
V_001_one.sql
```

Solution here is to delete from schema_version

```
V_005_five.sql
V_004_four.sql
```

AND revert any database changes caused. for example if schema created new table then you must drop that table before you run you migrations.

when you run flyway it will only re apply

```
V_005_five.sql
* V_004_addUserTable.sql *
```

new schema_version will be

```
V_005_five.sql
* V_004_addUserTable.sql *
V_003_three.sql
V_002_two.sql
V_001_one.sql
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @user5707585 This should be the accepted answer, as it actually helps provide a solution to your problem, rather than condescending general counsel on what you shouldn't have done to begin with.

Answer (score 11):

If you are sure that the modification in the SQL file has no impact on your existing schema, you can also update the checksum of the existing schema.

I did this following a slight change in the sql file.

Here is how I updated the checksum:

```
update flyway_schema_history set checksum = '-1934991199' where installed_rank = '1';
```

Answer (score 5):

What I did when faced this issue, was connect to DB and update the checksum field correspondent to the mistaken version, putting there the value resolved locally by FlyWay.

For the following error:

```
nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed.
Migration Checksum mismatch for migration 1.12
    -> Applied to database : 1029320280
    -> Resolved locally    : -236187247
```

I simply did this:

```
UPDATE schema_version SET checksum = -236187247 WHERE version_rank = 12 AND checksum = 1029320280;
```

And problem solved..

**NOTE:** You have to be sure your schema is actually correct, check your tables and their structure, if everything is OK, then you can apply this solution; otherwise, you should repair your schema manually first using plain and native SQL.

Answer (score 4):

Flyway changed the way it calculates the checksums from version 3 to version 5. You can re-calculate the checksums. Since the Flyway plugin doesn't properly read the Spring datasource properties, you have to manually specify them on the command line ([or one of the other various ways Flyway accepts](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/#system-properties)).

```
mvn flyway:repair -Dflyway.user=root -Dflyway.password= -Dflyway.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase -Dflyway.table=schema_version
```

Flyway also changed the table it stores the checksums, so you also have to specify `flyway-table=schema_version` to use your old table, or else it will give you a warning (and probably an error in version 6).

```
[INFO] Repairing Schema History table for version 2 (Description: create sources, Type: SQL, Checksum: 2125962141)  ...
[INFO] Repairing Schema History table for version 3 (Description: create stats, Type: SQL, Checksum: 389912194)  ...
[INFO] Repairing Schema History table for version 4 (Description: add user encrypted, Type: SQL, Checksum: 182607572)  ...
```

Answer (score 4):

use this query in your local DB.

1. select * from schema_version
   delete from schema_version where **checksum Column** =  -1729781252;

   Note: -1729781252 is the "Resolved locally" value.
2. Build and start the server.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I believe this occurred because of checksum between linux and windows (also mac).
you can `use repair()` command in flyway.

```
flyway.repair();
```

Be careful , if you are in production environment , make sure that you did not change the migration SQL file; because when you run the `flyway.repair();` it means you saying to flyway that your are sure about the migration version and their checksum and then the flyway repair them !

Answer (score 3):

Just add

```
spring.flyway.enabled=false
```

in application.properties file if you do not want flyway to check the checksum every time you run the application.

Answer (score 3):

After your .sql applied to DB, you edited the .sql, flyway may show this error.

If using Postgresql, a quick solution

After dropping tables "flyway_schema_histrory" and the table my .sql created, the error disappeared.
[delete table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjJZM.png)

Answer (score 2):

Update your schema_version record to mach the "Resolved locally" value which in your case is -1729781252

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is another solution, but it's a workaround, that should not be done in a properly managed project. However I met a situation, where it was not possible to go down the better road :)

You can update the schame_version table, and actually change the checksum to the new one. This will cause the migration to go through, but can have other side effects.

When deploying to different environments (test, uat, prod, etc) then it might happen, that you have to update the same checksum on more environments. And when it comes to gitflow, and release branches, you can easily mix up the whole.

Answer (score 2):

simple solution will be change spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/dasboot in application.properties to new file name like : spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/**dasboots**

Answer (score 2):

1-Delete the migration file.
2-connect to your database and drop the table created by the migration.
3-recreate the file of the migration with the the right sql.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this error with these steps:

1. In your database, go to the flyway_schema_history table
2. Delete the last row containing the most recent flyway migration script ("V6__xxx" or whatever)
3. Start your application.  I got another flyway error message that was kind of a dump of SQL to insert some rows in some tables.
4. Go to those tables and delete those new rows.

I think the flyway migration script was trying to run, but it had already run once.  It was trying to do the same thing again - insert the same rows - and that was the final conflict/error.  Deleting those rows allowed it to run normally/successfully

Answer (score 0):

If you have your problem in production, you must have **V2__create_shipwreck.sql** identically to the one you have in your latest version where it has not been modified.

Then the checksum will be correct again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried all the options (delete schema, delete specific row, update checksum) but nothing works.

In my case flyway-core dependency got corrupted somehow.

Solution:

1. Delete flyway-core folder from ~.m2\local repository path...\org\flywaydb\flyway-core.
2. Execute "maven clean install" so that it will download new one and add it into a project.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to solve this issue while development. Any one from below can solve this issue.
1) provide the changes in new migration sql file with incrementing version 
2) change the schema name in db url we provide 
   datasource.flyway.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/cart3  
   datasource.flyway.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/cart4  
3) delete the .mv and .trace files in users home directory    
   ex: cart3.mv  and cart3.trace   under c://users/username/

Answer (score -1):

just don't validate:

```java
flyway.setValidateOnMigrate(false);
```

Comment: That is not a good practice. Because if the migration is already applied, any change into that migration won't be reflected into DB, and you won't even get error, if you skip validation.

Comment: yes, but in case you have upgraded flyway version and found out it causes error, this can help.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced similar issue once. And the solution was...

Don't do any changes to DAO classes.. .It will try to change the database and flyway will not allow.

Answer (score -1):

Believe or not, adding flyway dependency version solved my issue

Answer (score -1):

As of writing this in 2023, I am using **Flyway 8.5.13** and I faced this issue when I tried to change the script that had already executed.

**What caused the issue:**

I changed name of the primary key column in V1 SQL script (after it had already been executed).

**How I resolved it:**

1. By undoing the changes I made to primary key column. Basically making V1 script same as it was before execution.
2. Added a new V2 sql file for changing the primary key column name.
3. Execute

Hope it helps